# ZeroMQ 'Restart' if no reply was recieved

Tags: python, zeromq

I have a python program which sends height data from my client to my server program. My server program will not be always running so if I don't recieve a response I would like it to try again.

So far what I have is that if a response (from the server) is not given in 20 Seconds it causes an exception and recalls my input. It works fine until I try it a second time.

Here is my code:

```
import zmq
from time import sleep

global radius
context = zmq.Context()
print("Remote Deployment Application")
print("Lightweight ZMQ Communication")
print("Connecting to Desk Ctrl Service")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.1.9:5555")
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 30000)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0) 


#  Do 10 requests,waiting each time for a response
def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height

def start():
    global height
    height = input("Enter in request: ")
    SendHeightVal()


def SendHeightVal():
    global userinput
    global height
    print("Sent Request. Awaiting Reply.")
    so_bytes = height.encode()
    socket.send(so_bytes)
    so_bytes = 0
    try:
       message = socket.recv()
    except:
        print("Something went wrong. No response from server!")
        message = None       
        start()    
    print(message)
    start()
```

Here is the error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 44, in <module>
    start()
  File "client.py", line 22, in start
    SendHeightVal()
  File "client.py", line 37, in SendHeightVal
    start()
  File "client.py", line 22, in start
    SendHeightVal()
  File "client.py", line 30, in SendHeightVal
    socket.send(so_bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 391, in send
    return super(Socket, self).send(data, flags=flags, copy=copy, track=track)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 727, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 774, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 249, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 244, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._send_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
```

Comment: Is using [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) an option? This will give you the ability to time out things inside an event loop.

Comment: @tadman a lovely profile-motto, Sir. On O/P: the ZeroMQ is intended to be as lightweight as possible ( Martin Sustrik's nanomsg being even more on diet in striving on achieving this Zen-of-Zero ), so it seems a just-enough tool for this level of composition ( simple system ). For complex Projects, where many-thousands of man*years have already been invested into the as-is code-base, the frameworks like you mention are not an option, but a heavily invested Value-at-Risk if people and teams are getting replaced with others, lacking the domain expertise. Hard to decide on a greenfield start-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lets start with a simple inventory of mandatory features:

> <sup>" *[agent-A]* **sends height data** from my client to my server program. My server program *[agent-B]* **will not be always running** so if I don't receive a response I would like it *[agent-A]* to **try again**."</sup>

For this,
the **`REQ/REP`** hard-wired two-step of
*[**A**].send()-[B].recv()-[B].send()-[**A**].recv()-[**A**].send()-[B].recv()-...*
is not the promising, the less a safe choice.

1 ) always set **`zmq.LINGER = 0`** to avoid zombies & hangups ( +1 for doing that )

2 ) if need not keep all *[A]*-side data delivered, may enjoy **`zmq.IMMEDIATE`** to deliver only to live *[B]* and **`zmq.CONFLATE`** to deliver only the most "fresh" values the *[A]*-side did `.send()`

3 ) if need in a need to keep all *[A]*-side data delivered, will have to either re-factor the strategy of sending on *[A]*-side become robust to missing *[B]*-side, so as to avoid blind and just optimistic data-pumping into the `Context()`-instance controlled, but rather expensive and quite limited resources, or carefully plan and pre-allocate due capacities, so as to remain able to indeed internally store all of 'em till the *[B]*-comes ( or not ) somewhere unsure in the future or the *[A]*-side dropping or blocking or exceptions will be unavoidable.

4 ) never expect the built-in trivial ( primitive ) archetypes to match your production needs, these come as a sort of LEGO-building blocks for some smarter, problem-specific distributed signalling and messaging infrastructure, not as a magic wand to solve all properties ( principally unknown and undefined at the time of these primitive-tools implementation ), so more engineering efforts will come, as one moves outside of school-book examples into designing robust distributed systems. Here could be a way using a composition of `{ PUSH/PULL + PULL/PUSH | PAIR/PAIR | XREQ/XREP }` plus heart-beating watchdog and re-discovery of remote agent(s). Some other archetypes may get later added for N+1 fault resilience or performance boosting with workload balancers or remote-console or latency motivated off-site remote-logging - if needed, all depending on hell many details that are beyond the initial post or a few SLOCs.

5 ) always handle exceptions, even if "masters" tell you one need not do that. Why? In [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) any problem cease to be a just-local isuue, so unhandled exceptions, fallen into a silent death of some agent will result in global impacts of missing such agent ( many ) others do rely on and may easily got blocked without any local-reason visible to 'em.

6 ) in production domain, there will be more efforts needed for protecting any smart infrastructure from remote-failures and also DoS-alike events, that impact local-`Context()` SPOF, so indeed the [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) architecture design is both very interesting and quite demanding domain.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html), you will find this:

> socket zmq.REQ will block on send unless it has successfully received a reply back.

Which means that you cannot send another request until receiving an answer. ZMQ has different messaging patterns the one you are using Client / Server `zmq.REQ` / `zmq.REP`.

> Any attempt to send another message to the socket (zmq.REQ/zmq.REP), without having received a reply/request will result in an error:

```
....
socket.send ("Hello")
socket.send ("Hello1")
....

Error: zmq.core.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
```

That's why your are getting the exception:

`zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state`

Comment: Ok I understand. Is their a way around this? Can I have it so that if I don't get a reply it will pretty much reset the socket and get rid of that message that is sitting there waiting for a reply so a new one can be sent?

Comment: With all due respect, this is just a part of the truth. **`zmq.REQ`** can unlock this one particular detail with setting a `zmq.REQ_RELAXED` but the problem solution for a robust, production-grade data exchange are much wider.

Comment: @user3666197 Can you please point me to `zmq.REQ_RELAXED` documentation? I coudn't find it in ZMQ API reference.

Comment: Which API version do you follow to use?

Comment: Version 4.2 stable.

Comment: Native 4.2 API is fine, just keep reading setsockopt details till the REQ_RELAXED option ( supported already in 4.1 )

Comment: Founded here http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt in 4.2 I was reading 3.1 by mistake. Thanks

Comment: *Found it ;- ) .